# Select change Event not working on Android WebView

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, webview

I have this piece of code on my **WEB APP**:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    $(".radius").on('change',function(){
        $("#cercadeMiForm").submit();
    });
});
```

No if I run this on my website, every time I change selection on the combo with class "radius", my form gets submitted properly.

If I run it on my mobile device standalone browser app, it works as well.

However, when I run it in my own app's webview, it does not work. I am using jQueryMobile and it seems to be working okay so I guess it's not a jQuery thing.

This is where I initialize my **WebView**:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(Constants.USER_AGENT);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake when posting the question.